# C++ async segment fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, future

So I wrote the following piece of code. It sometimes gets:

> segment fault::11

But sometimes doesn't. Could you explain why?

I'm also curious about the following questions.
In general, how does c++ assigns threads to / when does c++ executes `launch::async` and `launch::defferred` functions? Is there any disadvantage of `std::wait` over `std::get` if it's a `future<void>`?

```
std::future<void>r1, r2, r3, r4, ret;
//sometimes seg fault, sometimes pass
void f(int id, int t) {
    printf("call f(%d)\n", id);
    int ans=0;
    if (id == 3) {
      printf("wait 3\n");
      if (r1.valid()) r1.wait();
    }
    if (id == 4) {
      printf("wait 4\n");
      if (r1.valid()) r1.wait();
  }
  printf("start f(%d)\n",id);
  cnt[id]++;
  for (int i=1;i<=t;i++) {
      ans++;
  }
  printf("end f(%d)\n", id);
}

int main() {
  r3=async(f, 3, 1e8);
  r4=async(f, 4, 1);

  r1=async(f, 1, 1e8);
  r2=async(f, 2, 1e2);


  ret=async([&]() { r1.wait();r2.wait();r3.wait();r4.wait(); printf("cnt=%d,%d,%d,%d\n", cnt[1],cnt[2],cnt[3],cnt[4]); });

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: declaration of `cnt` ?  1 based array indexing is a point of concern.

Comment: What is cnt? Count? Why not call it count? That isn't defined anywhere. It would help if there were some meaningful variable names. And you are referencing r1 if `id==4 or 3`. With an async call, there's no guarantee that r1 is initialized, so a call to r1.valid() could cause a seg fault.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider You can call `valid()` on a default-constructed future. It just returns `false`.

Comment: You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there's too many possibilities for someone to guess about the rest of your code

Answer (score 1):

> It sometimes gets:
>
> segment fault::11
>
> But sometimes doesn't. Could you explain why?

I assume that `cnt` is properly declared so that there is no out-of-bounds access. If that's the case, then I think the problem here is that `std::future` objects are not thread-safe, so the calls to `r1.valid()` and `r1.wait()` race with the assignment to `r1` occurring in `main`. Such a data race causes undefined behaviour.

It looks like you should move the line

```
r1=async(f, 1, 1e8);
```

to the beginning of `main`. The write to `r1` will then be sequenced before the calls to `std::async` for `r3` and `r4`. The invocation of `std::async` synchronizes with the corresponding invocations of `f`. So the write to `r1` happens before the calls to `r1.wait` in `f`. The `future::wait` member function is `const`, so two threads can call it concurrently without racing.

For more complicated cases you can use `std::packaged_task` (which will let you obtain the `std::future` first and launch later, if you want) or `std::promise`.

> In general, how does c++ assigns threads to / when does c++ executes `launch::async` and `launch::defferred` functions?

If you're asking how `std::async` chooses which strategy to use when you give it a choice, the answer is that it's unspecified.